# Window doesn't show up (x86 ASM, Windows)

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86, fasm

I'm trying to open a window with a listbox in there. Nothing happens though, it stays open for about 5 seconds in Windows' task manager and then closes.

I'm using Flat Assembler (http://flatassembler.net/) to assemble and link my program.

```
    format PE GUI 4.0
    entry Start
    jp Start
    include 'win32a.inc'

    library kernel, 'KERNEL32.DLL', \
            user,   'USER32.DLL',   \
            gdi,    'GDI32.DLL'

    import kernel,\
           GetModuleHandle,  'GetModuleHandleA',\
           ExitProcess,      'ExitProcess'

    import user,\
           RegisterClass,    'RegisterClassA',  \
           CreateWindowEx,   'CreateWindowExA', \
           DefWindowProc,    'DefWindowProcA',  \
           SetWindowLong,    'SetWindowLongA',  \
           RedrawWindow,     'RedrawWindow',    \
           GetMessage,       'GetMessageA',     \
           TranslateMessage, 'TranslateMessage',\
           DispatchMessage,  'DispatchMessageA',\
           SendMessage,      'SendMessageA',    \
           LoadCursor,       'LoadCursorA',     \
           LoadIcon,         'LoadIconA',       \
           LoadMenu,         'LoadMenuA',       \
           GetClientRect,    'GetClientRect',   \
           MoveWindow,       'MoveWindow',      \
           SetFocus,         'SetFocus',        \
           MessageBox,       'MessageBoxA',     \
           PostQuitMessage,  'PostQuitMessage', \
           ShowWindow,       'ShowWindow'

    import gdi,\
           DeleteObject,     'DeleteObject'


    MENU_FILE_OPEN  = 101
    MENU_FILE_EXIT  = 102
    MENU_HELP_ABOUT = 901

Start:
    invoke GetModuleHandle, $00
    mov    [wc.hInstance],  eax
    invoke LoadIcon,        eax, $11
    mov    [wc.hIcon],      eax
    invoke LoadCursor,      $00, IDC_ARROW
    mov    [wc.hCursor],    eax
    invoke RegisterClass,   wc
    test   eax,             eax
    jz     Error

    invoke LoadMenu, [wc.hInstance], $25
    invoke CreateWindowEx, $0, str_win_class, str_title,\
                           WS_VISIBLE + WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, $20, $20\
                           $100, $da, $0, eax, [wc.hInstance], $0
    mov    [hWnd], eax
    test   eax, eax
    jz     Error

    invoke ShowWindow, hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL

MessageLoop:
    invoke GetMessage, message, NULL, $0, $0
    cmp    eax, $1
    jb     EndLoop
    jne    MessageLoop
    invoke TranslateMessage, message
    invoke DispatchMessage,  message
    jmp    MessageLoop

Error:
    invoke MessageBox, NULL, str_error_open, str_error_title,\
                       MB_ICONERROR + MB_OK

EndLoop:
    invoke ExitProcess, [message.wParam]



proc WindowProc hWnd, wMsg, wParam, lParam
    push   ebx esi edi
    cmp    [wMsg], WM_CREATE
    je     .wmcreate
    cmp    [wMsg], WM_SIZE
    je     .wmsize
    cmp    [wMsg], WM_SETFOCUS
    je     .wmsetfocus
    cmp    [wMsg], WM_COMMAND
    je     .wmcommand
    cmp    [wMsg], WM_DESTROY
    je     .wmdestroy

  .defwndproc:
    invoke DefWindowProc, [hWnd], [wMsg], [wParam], [lParam]
    jmp    .finish

  .wmcreate:
    invoke GetClientRect, [hWnd], client
    invoke CreateWindowEx, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, str_listbox, $0, WS_VISIBLE +    \
                           WS_CHILD + WS_VSCROLL + ES_AUTOVSCROLL,            \
                           [client.left], [client.top], [client.right],       \
                           [client.bottom], [hWnd], $0, [wc.hInstance], $0
    or     eax, eax ; To check if EAX equals zero
    jz     .failed
    mov    [listHWnd], eax
    xor    eax, eax
    jmp    .finish

  .failed:
    or     eax, -1
    jmp    .finish

  .wmsize:
    invoke GetClientRect, [hWnd], client
    invoke MoveWindow, [listHWnd], [client.left], [client.top], [client.right],\
                       [client.bottom], $1
    xor    eax, eax
    jmp    .finish

  .wmsetfocus:
    invoke SetFocus, [listHWnd]
    xor    eax, eax
    jmp    .finish

  .wmcommand:
    mov    eax, [wParam]
    and    eax, $ffff
    cmp    eax, MENU_FILE_OPEN
    je     .open
    cmp    eax, MENU_FILE_EXIT
    je     .wmdestroy
    cmp    eax, MENU_HELP_ABOUT
    je     .about
    jmp    .defwndproc

  .open:
    ; TODO Ask the user which file to open
    invoke MessageBox, [hWnd], str_info_todo, str_title_todo,                 \
                       MB_ICONINFORMATION + MB_OK
    xor    eax, eax
    jmp    .finish

  .about:
    invoke MessageBox, [hWnd], str_about_text, str_about_title, MB_OK
    xor    eax, eax
    jmp    .finish

  .wmdestroy:
    invoke PostQuitMessage, $0
    xor    eax, eax

  .finish:
    pop    edi esi ebx
    ret
endp

    str_title       db 'MegaChip8 Emulator', $00
    str_error_title db 'Error', $00
    str_error_open  db 'Couldn', $27, 't open window!', $00
    str_win_class   db 'MEGACHIP8', $00
    str_listbox     db 'LISTBOX', $00
    str_info_todo   db 'This function is still on the to-do list.', $00
    str_title_todo  db 'To-Do', $00
    str_about_title db 'About MegaChip8 Emulator', $00
    str_about_text  db 'This emulator is written by Sijmen "Vijfhoek" Schoon.',\
                       $0d, $0a, 'All rights reserved.', $00

    message MSG
    wc WNDCLASS 0, WindowProc, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, COLOR_BTNFACE + 1,\
                NULL, str_win_class
    client RECT

    hWnd dd ?
    listHWnd dd ?
```

Comment: It's hard to debug assembler in your head ;) Suggestion: Find something that works and compare to that, or start from what works and slowly work your way towards what this is.

Comment: Are you getting any messages in your WindowProc?

Comment: I tried comparing it to the included MINIPAD example (a really simple text editor), but I really can't find what I did wrong.

Comment: @HerrJoebob I am afraid it doesn't hit it. I tried putting an INT $3 in it, but OllyDBG doesn't stop on it (I'm not too familiar with Olly though, I might be doing it wrong)

Comment: Where does it get to then? Return values from the functions that do execute might be helpful.

Comment: A weird thing I just found out about, if I put a invoke MessageBox at the beginning just below Start:, nothing appears. I might be missing some kind of initialization or something?

Comment: @Stan there is, Ctrl+F MessageLoop. And isn't WinMain a C thing?

Comment: I'm having some serious trouble using OllyDBG. I placed an INT $3 after each invoke, but it seems to completely ignore them. If I try to step over them, it will error out on the calls, erroring about inaccessable memory.

Comment: Try removing the import statements and include api\user32.inc (and gdi and kernel) instead. It looks like the FASM headers do some extra macro magic that might be necessary (guessing).

Comment: What if you just open it in Olly, so that it stops on first command? If it doesn't, there's init problem, most probably with imports.

Comment: @AlekseyIvchenko It does stop on the first command. When I try to step over the call, it stops and generates that error.

Comment: ok, step inside and look, where it leads to - if module is right, if it jumps to the right place - Olly does recognize symbols, so you'll see instantly, if it is the right place. Then check stack, if it has correct amount of params and return address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since I also use FASM, it is simplier to try myself and find out, what is the problem.
You have obviously forgotten to declare sections. So, you do not have 'import' section => Windows doesn't bind DLLs for you. Here is correct code:

```
format PE GUI 4.0
entry Start
include 'win32a.inc'

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

library kernel, 'KERNEL32.DLL', \
        user,   'USER32.DLL',   \
        gdi,    'GDI32.DLL'

import kernel,\
       GetModuleHandle,  'GetModuleHandleA',\
       ExitProcess,      'ExitProcess'

import user,\
       RegisterClass,    'RegisterClassA',  \
       CreateWindowEx,   'CreateWindowExA', \
       DefWindowProc,    'DefWindowProcA',  \
       SetWindowLong,    'SetWindowLongA',  \
       RedrawWindow,     'RedrawWindow',    \
       GetMessage,       'GetMessageA',     \
       TranslateMessage, 'TranslateMessage',\
       DispatchMessage,  'DispatchMessageA',\
       SendMessage,      'SendMessageA',    \
       LoadCursor,       'LoadCursorA',     \
       LoadIcon,         'LoadIconA',       \
       LoadMenu,         'LoadMenuA',       \
       GetClientRect,    'GetClientRect',   \
       MoveWindow,       'MoveWindow',      \
       SetFocus,         'SetFocus',        \
       MessageBox,       'MessageBoxA',     \
       PostQuitMessage,  'PostQuitMessage', \
       ShowWindow,       'ShowWindow'

import gdi,\
       DeleteObject,     'DeleteObject'


MENU_FILE_OPEN  = 101
MENU_FILE_EXIT  = 102
MENU_HELP_ABOUT = 901

section '.text' code readable executable

Start:
invoke GetModuleHandle, $00
mov    [wc.hInstance],  eax
invoke LoadIcon,        eax, $11
mov    [wc.hIcon],      eax
invoke LoadCursor,      $00, IDC_ARROW
....
```

When sections aren't declared, FASM adds one - ".flat" to make file normal PE. But it doesn't have import flags. That's why there was a problem with setting breakpoints.

Comment: Yay, that fixed it! Thanks! I can't upvote your answer (need 3 more reputation, will do whenever I get them).